# Is it possible to deploy Orbeon on Oracle Weblogic 12c?

Tags: weblogic12c, orbeon

I am trying to deploy Orbeon PE 2016.3 on Weblogic 12c with no luck.

I have tried to deploy the orbeon.war as is to weblogic, also tried along with the other wars that were included in the zip package and the solution suggested in Orbeon [documentation](https://doc.orbeon.com/installation/weblogic.html) to create a custom EAR to avoid some weblogic 11g dependencies.

The stacktrace I get is:

```
Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.orbeon.oxf.util.DateUtils$
    at org.orbeon.oxf.common.PEVersion$LicenseInfo$$anonfun$8.apply(PEVersion.scala:169)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.common.PEVersion$LicenseInfo$$anonfun$8.apply(PEVersion.scala:169)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.common.PEVersion$LicenseInfo$.apply(PEVersion.scala:169)
    at org.orbeon.oxf.common.PEVersion$LicenseInfo$$anonfun$tryApply$1.apply(PEVersion.scala:175)
```

If I add joda.time to the prefered application packages in weblogic-application.xml this error disappears, but not sure if that is all.

Also when Orbeon is loaded in Weblogic I get the following error:

```
 <Error> <Weblogic-Validation> <BEA-2156404> <Unable to find a Validation Context. java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: String index out of range: -1
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.naming.NamingException: String index out of range: -1
    at weblogic.validation.ValidationContextManager.getValidationContext(ValidationContextManager.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.naming.NamingException: String index out of range: -1
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:311)
    at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:288)
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
```

I also noticed that the ASCII art in the logs is shown 1 time, then 2 times together (Orbeon Forms, Orbeon Forms) and then 3 times.

Comment: The second error is JNDI-related. Does that mean that you are using a datasource?

Comment: I haven't set a datasource yet.

Comment: Does the full stack trace provide more information about that error? Like is it part of an Orbeon stack trace?